# Exclude installed packages from the package lists that are proposed for emerging in Gentoo Linux?

Tags: gentoo

Taking a simple example:

run the following commands in a gentoo machine with htop installed:

```
emerge -av htop
```

The system will start compilling htop package regardless whether htop has been installed or not.

What I wish to achieve is to give a parameter to emerge so that if htop is installed with the same flag, it wouldn't reinstall it.

I am on the processe of installing a software package, which gives me a huge list of packages for emerging. however, some of them have already installed. I hope this method is able to neglect the packages installed in my pc.

Thanks.

Comment: you can write a bash script something like `for i in htop firefox chromium; do if ! equery l "$i" > /dev/null; then emerge -av "$i"; fi; done`

Comment: Yes, but I feel there may be one flag in emerge that directly does that. Yum and apt-get enable that by default.

Comment: Emerge will always rebuild the package you give it even if the use flags did not change. Since you are using '-a' you can say no. If other dependencies are being rebuilt it is probably because the use flags have change. There are a number of places use flags can be changed. http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-x86.xml?part=2&chap=2#doc_chap2_sect4 Your profile use flags can be changed with a emerge --sync. This may be what happened in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Use emerge option:

```
--noreplace, -n
```

> Skips the packages specified on the command-line that have already been installed. Without this option, any package atoms or package sets you  specify  on  the  command-line  will  cause Portage  to remerge the package, even if it is already installed.  Note that Portage will not remerge dependencies by default. This option can be used to update the world file without re‐building the packages.

```
--selective
```

> This is identical to the --noreplace option.  Some options, such as --update (-u), --changed-use (-U), --newuse(-N), --noreplace, already imply --selective.  Use --selective=n if you want to forcefully disable --selective,  regardless  of other  options and always merge all packages